# How to get API Routes in Nextjs App Router to Act like Pages Router

Tags: next.js, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I want my NextJS App Router API code to execute on every page request from a browser. That is, when using API Routes with the Page Router I have code like this that gets executed on every request (in production mode).

/pages/api/route1.ts

```
export async function GET(request: Request) {
  return new Response(
    "Hello, from /api/test1/routes.ts " + new 
Date().toLocaleString()
  );
}
```

app/api/route1.ts

```
export async function GET(request: Request) {
  return new Response(
    "Hello, from /api/test1/routes.ts " + new 
Date().toLocaleString()
  );
}
```

That is to say, the result is that when I run the first code, the date changes on every request (in production), yet when I run the second code, the date sticks to whatever it was at build time.

My questions is, if I want to use the app router, how can I get the same behavior as I had before in the pages Router?

However, when I do basically the same thing with RSC's (React Server Components) technology using the App Router, the component is run at build time and never run again. Here is that code:

Comment: Your examples are the same, both [app router style](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers), and the third snippet (or maybe that's where you intended to put the second one?) is missing entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are experiencing is that the response of the route handler is considered to be static and thus cached because you don't use any dynamic functions such as accessing cookies, headers or accessing path or search parameters.

To fix this and force the route handler to be dynamically invoked on each request without any caching add the following route segment config option to your route handler:

```
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'
```

More details on the `dynamic` segment config options are described in [the Next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config#dynamic).

Comment: Thanks @Christian. That does make sense as that is the behavior I'm observing. Is there the equivalent of I think "SSG" where a page will re-render after it is stale? That is, if I have data driven stuff on a page that only changes every so often, I don't want to have to republish, or make the page hit the server on every request

Comment: @PeterKellner Yes, there is the `revalidate` route segment config option as well the same option for `fetch` calls in general. I highly recommend to thouroughly go through the Data Fetching and Caching chapters of the documentation which describes various options you have at your disposal. Set aside sufficient time to read them in their entirety as they are quite long.

Comment: Will do (again). Took me a long time to really figure out the page router. Definitely need to get my head around this.